# React native Filtering API flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building my first react native app and connected my app to a mockable API

Before had I had a data.js file, but recently wanted to test the app with an live API.

Now I'm having problems filtering trough my API. Before hand I would import my Data.JS file and extract the object and put it in my state. Then I would set that equal to the filteredObject.

Now I've replaced my data file with my API

I've got a test running [here](https://snack.expo.io/@salman15/sadistic-apple)

**What I'm expecting:**

To filter trough my FlatList

**What I'm getting:**

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'row.restraunt.indexOf')
```

**Fetching API**

```
export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ 
      isLoading: true,
    }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('https://demo3381137.mockable.io/')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.restraunts,


                }, function(){

                });

            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
```

**Filtering trough API**

```
setSearchText(event) {
    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;
    // const textLength = this.state.rows.length;

    const filteredTexts = this.state.dataSource.filter(row => {
      return row.restraunt.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        });
        console.log("text: " + JSON.stringify(filteredTexts));

    this.setState({ 
      searchText,
      filteredRows: filteredTexts
    });
    }
```

**List Component**

```
    renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>
                        {rowData.item.restraunt}, {rowData.item.type}
          </Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
```

**Rendering FlatList**

```
render() {

        if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
                <View style={styles.loading}>
                    <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
            )
        }

    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
      {console.log(this.state.dataSource)} 
            <View style={styles.SearchBarContainer}> 
                    <TextInput
                    placeholder="Search"
                  value={this.state.searchText}
                  onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
                  style={styles.searchBar}
                  underlineColorAndroid="black"
                  selectionColor="black"
                />
                </View>
        <FlatList
          style={styles.listContainer}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>   
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [data returned from your API](https://demo3381137.mockable.io/) is inconsistent; for some rows `restaurant` is not present.

Consider revising your `setSearchText()` method like so, to account for `row` items that do not include the `restraunt` string field:

```
setSearchText(event) {

    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;    

    const filteredTexts = this.state.dataSource.filter(row => {

      /* If row.restraunt is present as a string, and includes searchText */
      return (typeof row.restraunt === 'string') &&
              row.restraunt.includes(searchText) 
    });

    this.setState({ 
        searchText,
        filteredRows: filteredTexts
    });
}
```

Also note the use of [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) here, which you may find a more concise alternative for this filtering behaviour. Hope that helps!

#### Update

Also, for the filtering to take effect, remember to update the `data` prop on `<FlatList/>` to your states `filteredRows` field, rather than `dataSource`. Lastly, keep in mind that the filtering is also case-sensitive.

#### Update 2

To achieve the desired filtering behaviour, you could make the following adjustments to your component:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('https://demo3381137.mockable.io/')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            /* Keep this, we'll base filtering on this data set */
            dataSource: responseJson.restraunts,
            /* Add this, to track what is presented to the user */
            viewSource: responseJson.restraunts, 
        }, function(){

        });

    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

---

```
render() {

    if(this.state.isLoading){
        return(
            <View style={styles.loading}>
                <ActivityIndicator/>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.SearchBarContainer}> 
                <TextInput
                placeholder="Search"
                value={this.state.searchText}
                onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
                style={styles.searchBar}
                underlineColorAndroid="black"
                selectionColor="black"
            />
            </View>
        {/* Use state.viewSource as the data source for FlatList */}
        <FlatList
          style={styles.listContainer}
          data={this.state.viewSource}
          renderItem={this.renderRow}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} />
      </View>)
}
```

---

```
setSearchText(event) {

    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;    

    const filteredTexts = this.state.dataSource.filter(row => {

      /* When no search text present, do not apply filtering */
      if(!searchText) {
          return true;
      }

      /* If row.restraunt is present as a string, and includes searchText */
      return (typeof row.restraunt === 'string') &&
              row.restraunt.includes(searchText) 
    });

    this.setState({ 
        searchText,
        /* Update viewSource to ensure that filtered data is displayed */
        viewSource: filteredTexts
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When using your method the `FlatList` is empty until I search for an row.  I'm looking to isolate the `dataSource` and adding that data to the `filteredRows` like this `filteredRows:dataSource` in the API `this.state` function , but it returns with `dataSource not found`

Comment: You're welcome :-) If I understand correctly, you want all the `restaurant` data to be listed and visible by default, and then have the filtering only take effect when a search string is provided in the search field?

Comment: That's correct. That's the way it used to work with the data.js file

Comment: Yeah ` viewSource: responseJson.restraunts, ` helped! Thanks! Was not sure how to add a second variable.